# Using Impex how to export Import B2BCustomerUserPermission Relation

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

OUR Hybris environment is refreshing. Post refresh we have a requirement to retain the users and its user permission. We have exported users and user permission. We are struggling with creating Impex to link user and user permission using a flex query. Anyone know the impex to link the user and userpermission using flex query?

## ---- Extension: b2bcommerce ---- Type: B2BCustomer ----

"$customer_B2B_query=select {m:pk} from { B2BCustomer as m} "

"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""B2BCustomer.csv"" );"
insert_update B2BCustomer;\
pk[target=foreignPk];\
email[allownull=true];\
name;\
active[allownull=true];\
existingComUser;\
isDefaultAccountSet;\
syncToOkta;\
primaryB2BUnit(uid);\
backOfficeLoginDisabled;\
authorizedToUnlockPages[allownull=true];\
telephone;\
orderPin;\
sapIsReplicated;\
customerID;\
token;\
uid[unique=true,allownull=true];\
groups(uid);\
userPermissions(pk[target=foreignPk])
"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch(""$customer_B2B_query"", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1  );"

## ---- Extension: core ---- Type: UserPermission --------------------------

"$userpermissions_query=select {m:pk} from { UserPermission as m} "

"#% impex.setTargetFile( ""UserPermission.csv"" );"
insert_update UserPermission;\
pk[unique=true,alias=foreignPk];\
active;\
soldTo(uid);\
customer(uid);\
userRole(code);
userType(code)
"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch(""$userpermissions_query"", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1  );"

Now I need help with Impex to reimport link the bmpcustomer and userpemission.

Comment: Can you share the impex / flex that you used to export?

Comment: Added impex in the question. Any idea on what should be the impex to link the bmp customer and userpermission?

Comment: What's the problem if you use this impex? I think it will be OK to import it, since UserPermission contains customer and userRole. You just need to remove pk as the unique attribute, and maybe use customer as the unique column.

Comment: We have b2bcustomerUserPermissionRel type where the source is customer and target is user permission. Now I am struggling with writing impex of importing link between the customer and user permissions.